# What is the name of the verb form "I can" in the sentence "I think I can"?

Tags: verbs, complex-sentences

I know that "I can" is the direct object, but don't know what type of verb form it is i.e. participle, gerund, infinitive, etc.

Comment: There is a subject and a verb, so it's a clause. Clauses have more than one word; verb forms have only one word (phrasal verbs are an exception, but the verb parts are normal).

Answer (score 1):

The complete phrase is "I think that I can." "I can" is a subordinate clause. The connecting word "that" has been omitted.